# Can't access Brew PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've used Brew to install PostgreSQL.  I want to log in with `psql`. Since I haven't set a password I 'm trying to login without one.  When I try I get this:

```
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have this in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Brew is a clean install.  I believe I've removed all instances of postgres (`psql` doesn't run if I remove the brewed postgresql).

What am am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the file was not read properly.

1. make sure that you restarted the postgresql-server after editing the file
2. make really sure that it's restarted (I ran into this twice...)
3. try again.

I searched one day for one suche error and a simple restart was all that was needed.

Also: with the last homebrew-install I made, my current user was setup automatically without password. so I could just execute `psql template0` and was connected to the server.

From there, you can create databases, roles and so on.